# not able to understand return statement in isEmpty function of stack implementation

Tags: c++, c, stack

I have **isEmpty()** function in my stack. And it looks something like below.

```
bool Mystack<T>::isEmpty() const    //function 1
{
     if(top==-1)
          return true;
     else 
          return false;
}
```

I saw a couple of online code for **isEmpty()**, which I could not understand. Below is the snippet.

```
bool Mystack<T>::isEmpty() const    //function 2
{
    return top == -1;
}
```

**Question 1:** Are both the functions doing the exactly the same task?

**Question 2:** If yes, then can some one please explain how the syntax in function 2 performing its task without using any **if** statement.

Comment: I can understand its a basic question. But why negative vote!!!!

Comment: I strongly recommend you reading about `==` operator. Then analyze possible execution paths of instruction `if(B) return true; else return false;` for possible values `B` of `bool` type.

Comment: I generally use it with `if` statement and thus never got confused. But here I could not find `if`.

Comment: When `top == -1` is `true`, it returns `true`. When it is `false`, it returns `false`. So just return `top == -1` directly.

Comment: Now as I understood the concept, I realize it was a very kiddish question. Anyways Thanks @all

Comment: @tanz Programming is a bit like mathematics in this regard. There are only two categories of problems: not yet solved ones and obvious ones :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top == -1` is an expression. Assuming no operator overloads are involved, its return type is `bool`. It will have the value `true` if `top` equals `-1` and the value `false` if that's not the case.

`return top == -1;` means "return the value of the expression `top == -1`". As I've shown above, this value is either `true` or `false`. These coincide exactly with the values returned from the `if()`-based code, so the two codes are equivalent.

In my code, I tend to use parentheses around "syntactically unusual" return statements, and I consider `==` one of them. So I would write this in my code (and I would certainly prefer it to the `if` version):

```
return (top == -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both functions work exactly the same. They return whether `top` equals `-1`.

In the first code, this is written somewhat "explicitly" (from the reader's perspective). Its English equivalent would be (roughly):

> Evaluate the expression `top == -1`.
>   If the result is `true`, then return `true`, else return `false`.

The second code does it more subtly, and its rough English equivalent would be:

> Return the result of the expression `top == -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do exactly the same thing.

Think about the semantics of an `if` statement. The condition evaluates to a `bool` and is checked against `true`. `top==-1` will either evaluate to `true` or `false`, if it evaluates to `true` then the first form is executed and `true` is returned, otherwise the second form is evaluated and `false` is returned. This is exactly the same as the second version, just more verbose.

Comment: so mere `top==-1` gives the result as true or false. I was under impression that whole `if(top==-1)` is needed. Since I have always used `==` operator inside `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:** Yes, same task.

**Answer 2:** I have no exact idea of `c++`, but logically

```
return top == -1;
```

can be broken into

1. check if the value of `top` is equal to `1` or not.

   1.1 if equal, return `1` [or `TRUE`] (as a result of comparison success)

   1.2 if not, return `0` [or `FALSE`] (as a result of comparison failure)

As reference, from `C99` standard document, chapter 6.8.6.4, paragraph 3,

> If a return statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is
>   returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression.

and for that of `c++11`, chapter 6.6.3, paragraph 2,

> . . . A return statement with an expression of non-void type can be used only in functions returning a value; the value of the expression is returned to the caller of the function....